# JWT, Laravel Class Tymon\JWTAuth\MiddlewareGetUserFromToken does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I set up JWT (`tymondesigns/jwt-auth`) on my laravel 5.0.35 app. Authentication works great. But, when i use `jwt.auth` middleware there is an error: `exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Tymon\JWTAuth\MiddlewareGetUserFromToken does not exist'`

Your help would be appreciated))) Here are files that might be helpfull for you:

**app.php**

```
$providers = [
    // other records
    'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider',
];

'aliases' => [
    // other records
    'JWTAuth'   => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth',
    'JWTFactory' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory'
];
```

**kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\MiddlewareGetUserFromToken',
    'jwt.refresh' => 'TymonJWTAuth\MiddlewareRefreshToken'
];
```

**Contoller where I call `jwt.auth` middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Resources;

use IlluminateHttpRequest;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use App\User;


use PDO;
use Log;

class DirectionsController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware('jwt.auth');
   }
```

**compsoser.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "0.2.*",
    "irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk": "^2.0",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Comment: First, did you try a composer dump-autoload ?

Comment: @Roadirsh yes I did)

Comment: It need a slash in the kernel.php for jwt.refresh but it shouldn't fix your problem

Comment: which version of jwt do you use ?

Comment: I think if you add slash in kernel file like the below, Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken, it will solve the problem.

Comment: @Roadirsh thank your for reply. JWT version is 0.5.9

Comment: @suguna I tried, didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: @АкиИргашев  I think you didn't took the master branch can we see your composer.json file ?

Comment: @Roadirsh But it's not written in installation manual. Hovewer i followed your suggestion and tried, and it didn't help

Comment: yes sorry, I edited my comment :)

Comment: @Roadirsh again thank your for response) I added contents of composer.json in my question. Please look at the end of the question

Comment: Well, I don't really know sorry. I would just recommand you to replace `'Tymon\JWTAuth\MiddlewareGetUserFromToken'` by `Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class` in your kernel.php and see if your IDE can see the class. Try to see if you can find the file GetUserFromToken.php in your project.

Comment: @Roadirsh i found the error. Thank your for yor support) I tried to declare like this earlier Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class but it didn't work. There was a syntax error.

Answer (score 6):

I have found the error. The error is where there is a declaration of middleware in kernel.php

```
'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\MiddlewareGetUserFromToken',
'jwt.refresh' => 'TymonJWTAuth\MiddlewareRefreshToken'
```

So, instead of `MiddlewareGetUserFromToken` should be `Middleware\GetUserFromToken`. Looks like this type was in blog post where I copied it. Be careful when your copy code from other websites)

Comment: @sugana told you exactly to change that :o

Comment: @Roadirsh looks like I misunderstood you. if you want you can write as answer, i'll upvote and accept it